# How to detect an Ethernet device in the network (UDP)

Tags: python, udp, wireshark, scapy, ethernet

Hello everyone I need to establish a communication between my PC and a climate chamber.

It requires Modbus TCP, but first I have to detect my chamber in the network with UDP datagrams.

In the manufacturer documentation, they say that for the chamber detection I have to send a UDP broadcast (255.255.255.255) and `"GetConfigDirect"` (ASCII). The UDP port is 9001.

And I'm supposed to receive an answer with chamber information, but I don't receive anything.

I'm using Scapy and I wrote this :

```
packet = IP(dst="255.255.255.255") / UDP (dport = 9001) / Raw(load="GetConfigDirect")
```

I also tried this:

```
packet = IP(dst="255.255.255.255") / UDP (dport = 9001) / Raw(load="GetConfigDirectCRLF")
```

because it is written that telegrams must end with CRLF.

```
packet = IP(dst="255.255.255.255") / UDP (dport = 9001, sport=1900) / Raw(load="GetConfigDirect")
```

because it is one of the five UDP port of my computer when I do `netstat -a` with cmd.

When I send a packet with `send(packet)`, I have this:

```
WARNING: Mac address to reach destination not found. Using broadcast.
```

and I can see my datagram sent on Wireshark with the DNS protocol.

With `sendp(packet)`, nothing.

If I do `srp(packet)`, I have this:

```
INFO: DNS RR prematured end (ofs=9, len=9)
```

many times. All packets are received and I get no answer.

Finally I can also see Destination unreachable (Port unreachable) with the ICMP protocol on Wireshark.

[Picture of Scapy & Wireshark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OaGRA.png)

[Picture of the documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSwie.png)

My question is : Why do I have these errors and How can I solve my problem / How can I receive the chamber information as presented in the documentation.

Comment: Not posting an answer as I couldn't get a response from the etlservicemgr, but a few things: (1)CR-LF refers to  Carriage Return (ASCII 13, \r) Line Feed (ASCII 10, \n), so they mean add "\r\n" at the end of the data, not writing "CRLF". (2) You don't write it above but I assume you provide the interface name on send() command. (3) Pretty sure it isn't a must but you might want to add Ether() header before IP() with the interface MAC address as src and "ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff" as dst. This should eliminate the broadcast warning.

Comment: In your second test, shouldn'it be `Raw(load=b'GetConfigDirectCRLF\x0d\x0a')` to properly encode CR+ LF?  Here you send the plain `CRLF` string in your message not the two carriage return line-feed characters. (I haven't tested as I do not have a scapy installed right now.)

Comment: Hi, thank you both, I tried : packet = Ether (src="c8:d3:ff:73:74:9c", dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff") / IP(dst="255.255.255.255") / UDP (dport = 9001) / Raw(load=b'GetConfigDirectCRLF\x0d\x0a') and the other possibilities, but I have : Unknown operation (14) / Malformed packets on Wireshark ////// On cmd > scapy, with Ether now I have this when I do srp(packet) INFO: DNS wrong value: DNS.qdcount=28526
INFO: DNS wrong value: DNS.ancount=26217
INFO: DNS wrong value: DNS.nscount=26436
INFO: DNS wrong value: DNS.arcount=26994
.INFO: DNS RR prematured end (ofs=9, len=9) ............

Comment: About the interface name on send() command, I think I didn't provide it. Did I forget to add something? And how can I add this interface name?

Comment: By the way if I add sport = 1900, I don't send malformed packets error anymore. But I still have the "DNS RR prematured end" error on cmd>scapy and no answer.

Comment: This is how I tried: send(Ether(src="9c:b6:54:90:8a:60", dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")/IP(src="0.0.0.0", dst="255.255.255.255")/UDP(dport=9001)/Raw(load="GetConfigDirect\r\n"), iface="br0"). Just add 'iface=<name>' at the end. I used my management network interface you can look for it by using 'ifconfig'. Also, please remove 'CRLF' from your data text, there's no way it is needed and if they are looking for a specific string it will cause you issues.

Comment: I just made researches and I don't find my iface, I'm on Windows so I did ipconfig /all and nothing interesting. I've found that it could be "eth0", "eth1", ..., "ethX" but it doesn't run either. "OSError: b'eth0: No such device exists (No such device exists)'". Could you help me please?

Comment: With get_if_list() I have this : ['{698744E2-8364-4854-91CB-DF7048104DC8}', '{55156548-33CF-44B5-9C80-7575602965F8}', '{EF88B459-EDC7-47A2-95C6-6B24FD3A8485}', '{7202570C-7451-4364-A7DD-4863CCCA0BA4}', '{F3250D36-9E89-4374-B813-E98887BC85B9}', '{734DFD9A-AA81-46FD-A118-06199FF83F38}', '{9F317AD5-07CE-47A5-9FC4-E4486E377553}', '{1541C004-AF02-48EA-B850-270021FDA0CD}', '\\Device\\NPF_Loopback'], but I don't think these characters are iface?

Comment: Or maybe someone else could help me? :( I would be very grateful

Comment: What version of scapy are you using. If <2.4.5 start off by updating

Comment: Hi I'm using Scapy 2.4.5, I downloaded it three days ago